# How can you run a shell command in Blazor and get the output?

Tags: shell, blazor-webassembly

I'm running this in a Blazor WASM app.  In my Shared project I have the following class.

```
public static class ShellHelper
{
  public static string ToBash(this string cmd)
  {
    var escapedArgs = cmd.Replace("\"", "\\\"");

    var process = new Process()
    {
      StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
      {
        FileName = "/bin/bash",
        Arguments = $"-c \"{escapedArgs}\"",
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
      }
    };
    process.Start();
    string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    return result;
    }
}
```

I then have a page in my Client project with the following code.

```
@page "/bash"

<h3>Bash</h3>

<input @bind="command" />
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="runCommand">Execute</button>
<p>Output:<br />
    The following command "@command" was run at @timestamp<br />
    @result</p>

@code {
    private string command { get; set; }
    private string timestamp { get; set; }
    private string result { get; set; }

    private void runCommand()
    {
        timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        try
        {
            result = command.ToBash();            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = ex.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

It's giving me the following output.

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Diagnostics.Process is not supported on this platform. at System.Diagnostics.Process..ctor() at Nexus.Shared.ShellHelper.ToBash(String cmd) in F:\Projects\Blazor Projects\Nexus\Nexus\Shared\ShellHelper.cs:line 16 at Nexus.Client.Pages.Bash.runCommand() in F:\Projects\Blazor Projects\Nexus\Nexus\Client\Pages\Bash.razor:line 22

I'm just wanting a way to run commands from my Blazor app, obviously I do this in a much more elegant way, but I'm trying to learn and test out how to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**"System.Diagnostics.Process is not supported on this platform"**

That is your answer. You cannot do what you are trying to do. You cannot use System.Diagnostics.Process in Blazor WASM.

You cannot start a system process from inside a web browser. It would be a major security issue if you could.

This code may work in using Blazor Server instead as the code would run on the server (which can use System.Diagnostics.Process) not in the browser.